# Batch insertion

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the following code which is working fine,
But I need a way to batch process it and 
Insert it all in one go.

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($my_array); $i++)
        {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO exclude_resource (id,resource_id,config_id)
                    VALUES(DEFAULT, '$my_array[$i]' ,'$insert_id')";

            $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
            $result = $command->execute();
        }
```

Comment: multi-query help you. :- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: improve your question title, it may attract downvoters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should resemble something like (see [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)):

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES
    (value1a, value2a, value3a),
    (value1b, value2b, value3b),
    (value1c, value2b, value3c),
    ...
```

So put the values in an array, join them with commas, and execute the resulting query. Incorporated in PHP:

```
$values = array();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($my_array); $i++) {
    $values[] = "(DEFAULT, '$my_array[$i]' ,'$insert_id')";
}

$sql = 
    "INSERT INTO exclude_resource (id,resource_id,config_id) VALUES '.
    join(',', $values);
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$result = $command->execute();
```

`$insert_id` is needs to have a value, but thats the same with your code snippet.

If you have more than 5k or 10k rows to insert, you should run an INSERT in between and reset the array.